# I just upgraded my wordpress to 6.0.3 and get a Fatal error after the upgrade

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, fatal-error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wp_get_attachment_thumb_file()
> (previously declared in
> /home/lh1fmg9r4ipw/public_html/wp-includes/post.php:6709) in
> /home/lh1fmg9r4ipw/public_html/wp-includes/deprecated.php on line 4327

I upgraded the wordpress version to 6.0.3 and I cannot get the site to work again.

attached is the error messages I see once i go to my site

In my error log I see a lot of

> "[29-Jan-2023 19:55:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare
> wp_get_attachment_thumb_file() (previously declared in
> /home/lh1fmg9r4ipw/public_html/wp-includes/post.php:6709) in
> /home/lh1fmg9r4ipw/public_html/wp-includes/deprecated.php on line
> 4327"

Here is wp-includes/deprecated.php on line> 4327

```
/**
 * Retrieves thumbnail for an attachment.
 * Note that this works only for the (very) old image metadata style where 'thumb' was set,
 * and the 'sizes' array did not exist. This function returns false for the newer image metadata style
 * despite that 'thumbnail' is present in the 'sizes' array.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 * @deprecated 6.1.0
 *
 * @param int $post_id Optional. Attachment ID. Default is the ID of the global `$post`.
 * @return string|false Thumbnail file path on success, false on failure.
 */
function wp_get_attachment_thumb_file( $post_id = 0 ) {
    _deprecated_function( __FUNCTION__, '6.1.0' );

    $post_id = (int) $post_id;
    $post    = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        return false;
    }
    

    // Use $post->ID rather than $post_id as get_post() may have used the global $post object.
    $imagedata = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post->ID );

    if ( ! is_array( $imagedata ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $file = get_attached_file( $post->ID );

    if ( ! empty( $imagedata['thumb'] ) ) {
        $thumbfile = str_replace( wp_basename( $file ), $imagedata['thumb'], $file );
        if ( file_exists( $thumbfile ) ) {
            /**
             * Filters the attachment thumbnail file path.
             *
             * @since 2.1.0
             *
             * @param string $thumbfile File path to the attachment thumbnail.
             * @param int    $post_id   Attachment ID.
             */
            return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_thumb_file', $thumbfile, $post->ID );
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
```

Comment: The current WP version is 6.1.1 - I would try to upgrade to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe this is common knowledge but I went on the backup version. I replaced the "public_html" with on of the unzipped files in the "application_backups" folder. I will know update all the plugins first, then backup, then try to move to 6.1.1